# Update a row multiple time when data stream from Google Datastore to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are trying to push the datastore entities update to BigQuery as streaming input to provide the realtime data analysis.

Each entities in the datastore will be updated multiple times in a day. When we push the entities, I need to make sure that only latest data should be to bigquery record. How can I archive this?

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in streaming path to go from Datastore to BigQuery as far as I know. What is supported is making a Datastore backup (exported to Cloud Storage) and loading the backup into BigQuery with a load job.

Instead of using a job to load data into BigQuery, you can also choose to stream your data into BigQuery one record at a time by using the tabledata().insertAll() method. This approach enables querying data without the delay of running a load job.

Generally streamed data is available for real-time analysis within a few seconds of the first streaming insertion into a table. However data in the streaming buffer may be temporarily unavailable. When data is unavailable, queries continue to run successfully, but they skip some of the data that is still in the streaming buffer.

For more details you can check below links:

[Link-1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)
[Link-2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/980)